# AlertDialog.Builder open another AlertDialog.Builder

Tags: android, dialog, android-alertdialog

I'm trying to open a `AlertDialog` in another `AlertDialog`, but it's not working, any ideas why it's not working?

```
String items[] = {"Details","Edit","Delete"}
AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(getAplicationContext());
alert.setTitle("Options");
alert.setItems(items, new OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
        switch(item){
            case 0:
                AlertDialog.Builder alert2 = new AlertDialog.Builder(getAplicationContext());
                alert2.setTitle("Details");
                alert2.setMessage(getDetails());
                alert2.setNeutralButton("Close", null);
                alert2.show();
            return;

            case 1:
                //not important for the question
            return;

            case 2:
                //not important for the question
            return;
        }
    }
});

alert.setNegativeButton("Cancel", null);
alert.show();
```

Comment: Define "not working".  Do you receive any error messages when trying to open an `AlertDialog` in another `AlertDialog`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is probably the context you are using for the `AlertDialog`'s. Try using `MyActivityName.this` in both, replacing MyActivityName with whatever the name of your `Activity` is.

So, building the first `AlertDialog` should look like this

`AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(MyActivityName.this);`

and then

`AlertDialog.Builder alert2 = new AlertDialog.Builder(MyActivityName.this);`

for the second one.

Comment: @FelipeSuman It's customary on these forums to accept the answer (click the check mark next to it) when one has been found. Thanks and good luck!

Comment: it helped me with a similar problem, another upvote is needed